# single XML file but need to populate 2 dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, data-binding, visual-studio-2005

i have 2 dropdownlist to implement and the xml file is as follow:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<email>
  <builderemail>
    <builder id="1"  value="builder@xyz.com">
    </builder>
    <builder id="2" value="Others">
    </builder>
  </builderemail>
  <manageremail>
    <manager id="1" value="manager@xyz.com"></manager>
    <manager id="2" value="Others"></manager>
  </manageremail>
</email>
```

i am using visual studio 2005 and i tried to data bind each drop down list by choosing a data source. my requirements are that one of the drop downlist for builder's email and the other drop down list for manager's email.
How do i do that by using the datasource configuration wizard?

regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse xml and store the builderemail and manageremail in list, then provide as datasource to dropdown list

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(@"sample.xml");
    XmlNodeList builderNodes =  doc.GetElementsByTagName("builderemail");
    XmlNodeList mangerNodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("manageremail");


    List<string> builderMails = new List<string>();
    foreach (XmlNode node in builderNodes[0].ChildNodes)
    {
        builderMails.Add(node.Attributes["value"].Value);
    }

    List<string> mangerMails = new List<string>();
    foreach (XmlNode node in mangerNodes[0].ChildNodes)
    {
        mangerMails.Add(node.Attributes["value"].Value);
    }


     comboBox1.DataSource = builderMails;
        comboBox2.DataSource = mangerMails;
```

Comment: hi mahantesh, i do not understand parse xml. sorry i'm relatively new to programming

Comment: Get all the builderemails and manageremails seperately in list by parsing the xml provide as datasource.

Answer (score 0):

These links might help you out

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/xmlboundlistcontrol.aspx

http://dotnetspidor.blogspot.com/2009/04/bind-aspnet-dropdownlist-to-xml-file.html

But you might have to change your xml and structure it like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<email>
  <builderemail>
    <builder> 
      <id>1</id>  
      <value>builder@xyz.com</value>
    </builder>
  </builderemail>
  <manageremail>
    <manager> 
      <id>1</id>  
      <value>manager@xyz.com</value>
    </builder>
  </manageremail>
</email>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi divi, i tried your the 2nd link that you posted but i run into problems when i tried to key in a 2nd entry in the xml file. For example:  `<builder><id>1</id><value>builder@xyz.com</value><id>2</id><value>Others</value>`

Comment: Hi Jeremy, could you please try <builder><id>1</id><value>builder@xyz.com</value></builder><builder><id>2</id><value>Others</value></builder>, so that every builder only has 1 id and 1 value tag